# Get value of other label while applying filter on one label in PromQL

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a kubernetes cluster hosting multiple tenants. I want to filter out the nodes belonging to a particular tenant. For example:

Querying `kube_node_labels` to prometheus results in the following output:

```
kube_node_labels{ node="ip-10-139-110-166.ec2.internal", label_tenant: "tenant1" }
kube_node_labels{ node="ip-10-139-110-167.ec2.internal", label_tenant: "tenant2" }
kube_node_labels{ node="ip-10-139-110-168.ec2.internal", label_tenant: "tenant1" }
```

Is there a way I can just get all the nodes belonging to a particular tenant as array? For e.g. `ip-10-139-110-166.ec2.internal`, `ip-10-139-110-168.ec2.internal` for tenant1

Basically, what's the equivalent of
`select node` from `kube_node_labels` where `label_tenant="tenant1"` in PromQL?

Comment: Either you need `group by (node) (kube_node_labels{label_tenant="tenant1"})` (see https://promlabs.com/blog/2020/12/17/promql-queries-for-exploring-your-metrics#getting-all-values-for-a-specific-label) or you need to read https://promlabs.com/blog/2020/06/18/the-anatomy-of-a-promql-query

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: this didn't work for me, I think for grouping, you first also need to  apply some aggregation function

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it with the following query:
`label_values(kube_node_labels{label_tenant="tenant1"}, node)`